# Strange result when searching in ecoinventdb through BW2

Tags: brightway

I am a Brightway2 beginner. A result has complicated my life for a few weeks now and I can't find any solutions. I've dealt with it by various tricks but I would still like to understand this problem:
when I search in my database for an activity with the name "glazing" for example, I get activities like "phenol", "polysulfide production"... Even if I look at the description of these activities, I don't understand (and this complicates my life a little). (db = ecoinvent 3.6)
Any ideas? 
Maybe this is not the right place for this kind of question...
Thank you in advance.
Jean

```
code:
activity_name = 'glazing'
myProducts = []

for activity in Database("ecoinvent 3.6 APOS").search(activity_name, filter={"location" : 'RER'}): 
    myProducts.append(activity)
myProducts
```

out:

```
['glazing production, triple, U<0.5 W/m2K' (square meter, RER, None),
 'glazing production, double, U<1.1 W/m2K' (square meter, RER, None),
 'glazing production, double, U<1.1 W/m2K, laminated safety glass' (square meter, RER, None),
 'polysulfide production, sealing compound' (kilogram, RER, None),
 'phenol production' (kilogram, RER, None),
 'phenol production' (kilogram, RER, None),
 'methacrylic acid production' (kilogram, RER, None)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search is working as intended: You are looking for the term `glazing`, and it shows up in all the given results. For example the `comment` to `polysulfide production` has the sentence:

```
This dataset is primarily used in the glazing production.
```

If you only want activities with `glazing` in the title:

```
only_glazing = [ds for ds in Database("something") if 'glazing' in ds['name']]
```

You could also test against `ds['name'].lower()` to get case independence.

In general, searching with list comprehensions is going to produce more sensible results than `.search`, which is more for data exploration.